# SSL EOF occurred in violation of protocol with python httplib

Tags: ssl, certificate, httplib, httpserver

The current questions regarding this topic didn't solve my problem and neither has Google.

relevant server code:

```
class ReuseHTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    def __init__(self, address, handler, queue=None):
        BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, address, handler)

        self.address = address
        ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(self.address_family, self.socket_type),
                                     keyfile = KEY_PATH,
                                     certfile = CERTIFICATE_PATH,
                                     server_side = True,
                                     cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                                     ssl_version = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                                     ca_certs = CA_PATH)
        s = self.socket.getsockname()

        print "serving:", s[0], "on port:", s[1]

        self.socket = ssl_socket

        self.server_bind()
        self.server_activate()
```

client code:

```
conn = https.HTTPSConnection(HOST, port=PORT, key_file=KEY_PATH, cert_file=CERT_PATH)

        conn.putrequest("GET", '/cgi-bin/retrieveRunningInstances')

        conn.endheaders()

        response = conn.getresponse()
```

Trying to connect with the client gets an SSLError errno 8; EOF occurred in violation of protocol. I have verified the certificates using openssl. I am pulling my hair out. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

The error occurs during the handshake in `conn.getresponse()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I had the same problem:

> ```
> SSLError errno 8; EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> ```

It turned out that I had a missing cert_file.  I had specified one as follows, but did not have one.

```
server = HTTPServer( ('',5005), HttpHandler )
server.socket = ssl.wrap_socket( server.socket, certfile='kencert.pem', server_side=True )
```

When I added the .pem file it worked!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will look at that today. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Wasn't the exact answer, but the problem was with my cert file and your answer lead me in the right direction. Thanks!